# Сумма с накоплением в столбце

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, анализ-данных

У меня есть данные в следующем формате: месяц-доход за этот месяц (данные ниже).

Мне нужно создать новую колонку, где в каждом последующем месяце суммировался бы доход за все предыдущие. Сначала июнь, потом июнь+июль, потом июнь+июль+август и так далее. Чтобы получилось накопление.

Как это можно оптимально сделать?

```
purchase_month  revenue     
--------------  ---------
2018-03-01      207298.68
2018-04-01      131081.60
2018-05-01      88927.85
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [Series.cumsum()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html):

```
df["revenue_cum"] = df["revenue"].cumsum()
```